# image file out of date after delete or modify it in image.xcassets with Xcode5

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

every time I delete or modify the name of an image file in image.xcassets, then I submit to my svn server with Xcode source control,it just shows the svn of this file is out of date, and unable to be submitted,how to fix this ?thanks a lot.